# Hibernate 2 oracle db connection

Tags: hibernate

Given below is my Oracle db connection from cmd line & hibernate.cfg.xml.

`C:>sqlplus scott@orclpdb

SQL*Plus: Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on Sun Jan 14 18:23:34 2024
Version 21.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2021, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter password:
Last Successful login time: Sun Jan 14 2024 18:23:23 -05:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 21c Enterprise Edition Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 21.3.0.0.0

SQL> show user
USER is "SCOTT"
SQL>`

`

update  
        org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9Dialect  
        jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orclpdb  
        scott  
        password  
        oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver  
      
      
  
 `

I am running the example from the following website.

**https://www.javatpoint.com/example-to-create-hibernate-application-in-eclipse-ide**

Given below is the error i am getting from my hibernate example.

Is my hibernate.cfg.xml correct?

Where is it going wrong? Any help is appreciated.

**Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
The Connection descriptor used by the client was:
localhost:1521:orclpdb**

```
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:261)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:387)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:414)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:165)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:801)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:38)
... 27 more
```

Comment: Attached is the hibernate.cfg.xml.